# Setup multiple .env configurations (React/Next/Node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nestjs, dotenv

How to use multiple .env config files correctly for development / stage / production. I realize I need a .env file, use dotenv (at least), but when I start hosting my app (React), I use localhost: 5000 urls, but I have to use some service-host urls which I use.

Answer (score 0):

Your .env file is not commited.

So on you production build, you will configure your .env file to contain your production details. Again, .env files are private.

Your development .env file will contain details that you use for your localhost.

You can also, set a variable called to say `PROD_BASEURL` and then utilize an IF statement in your code.

```
if(PROD_BASEURL) {
  do stuff
}
```

To answer your question. No, you won't use multiple .env files to separate PROD/UAT/DEV

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use multiple .env files ?

The general recommendation is to have one unique `.env` file.

> Should I have multiple .env files?
>
> No. We **strongly** recommend against having a "main" .env file and an
> "environment" .env file like .env.test

link : https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file

Use a package like `dotenv` to manage your env variables. There are other package that do the same thing.

And you define your production env variables on your other, production server. The general recommendation is to have one .env file per host.

If you still need to however, you can use the following `dotenv` configuration :

> require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })

Remember to not store any secret in your `.env` file in your react app.